# Keycloak and Open ID Connect best practices

Tags: authentication, web-application, oauth, oauth2, openid-connect

I'm a bit lost as to the best practice surrounding a production-ready access management based on keycloak and open id connect.

My understanding is that if you use Keycloak's provided adapters, instead of writing your own, you end up with a cookie and a session, instead of using the JWT that is provided by the Keycloak OP.

First of all, why is it that the JWT token is not used to carry the authentication ? It somehow feels that the OIDC protocol is not complete if we need to add a layer on top of it, instead of just using it bare.

If I have a (back-end) Client that is composed of multiple spread out micro-services (APIs), what would be the best approach to configure Keycloak / OIDC / the client ? Should I stick to this session management that is proposed on top of the OIDC protocol, or should I use the JWT that is given by Keycloak ?

What about the other micro-services ? Should they also use that JWT token to authenticate each request that is made to them, or should they somehow propagate the session, or should I set up some network architecture where the server that is responding to the web requests is the only one that takes care of the authentication, and the other APIs are not accessible from the outside world but don't care about authentication (ie they trust each other) ?

What about the challenges that are specific to a production environment, how do they impact this decision making, and what are they and how to address them ? I'm thinking (but most likely not exhaustive) of things such as:

- user logout
- key/secret renewal
- compromised keys and access revocation

Thank you very much for reading my question.